# How to add @HandlerChain to wsdl/xml so that mvn/CXF generates it in SOAP Webservice/Client?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cxf

I have created a `@WebService` and `@WebServiceClient` from a WSDL-File

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" ...
```

and JaxWS-Bindings

```
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" ...
```

Those are referenced in my Maven pom.xml.

I can't find any useful information on how and where I can add a `HandlerChain`, So I can add `custom SOAPHandler's` for the service/client.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how a HandlerChain could be added to the WSDL/XML in a way the autogenerated result is correctly annotated but every Soap service has some kind of endpoint definition where it could be added like:

```
<jaxws:endpoint ...>
        <jaxws:handlers>...</jaxws:handlers>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```